# Can living things be transported directly into the Room of Requirement?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory, hogwarts

I know people can get into the Room of Requirement through the passageway leading from the Hog's Head. But can living, sentient beings like animals or people be transported into the RoR if you wish for it, or does the RoR only transport inanimate objects like books or Sneakoscopes?

Comment: We've never seen it create life, but that doesn’t mean it’s impossible. Life can apparently be created; for example, Hermione’s *Avis* charm.

Comment: The Vanishing Cabinet in the Room of Requirement allows people to be transported there from Borgin & Burke's. This was a major plot point in book 6. Not sure if that's what you mean by "transported"?

Comment: There seems to have been Cornish Pixies in [The Room of Hidden Things](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Room_of_Requirement#Behind_the_scenes).

Comment: @randal'thor: Sorry if I wasn't too clear about what I meant with transported. The Room of Requirement gets its things from other places; it can't make objects appear out of thin air, right? So when objects 'appear' there, they are actually being transported from another place.

Comment: @petra_delphiki - presumably, it can transfigure objects as well, though I am not sure JKR ever gave enough clear info. Great question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if the room of requirement was at any other location other than inside Hogwarts it could have. It transforms into whatever you require and fills itself with anything you need only if it is in bounds with the laws of magic at that place (e.g it cannot provide you with food - this is applicable globally). But Hogwarts has unprecedented security measures against people just appearing inside the castle through any means (yes it did miss out on the vanishing cabinet). Due to these restrictions on magic that could be performed in Hogwarts the Room of Requirement as mentioned in the story, cannot get people or living things inside the room.